# WP query to get upcomming events first and older events in the end using ACF date field

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get all events on a page, where I have older events and new events as well.

**But need to modify my query to first get Upcoming events (according to the current date) and then older events in the same query. Any help will be highly appreciated**

This code sorts the events from latest to oldest only

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => $arrayTypes, //type of posttypes i am working with
        'post__in' => $fp, //my specific IDs i need to work with
        'meta_key'            => 'event_date', //my ACF field name
        'orderby'            => 'meta_value',
        'order'                => 'ASC'
    );
$queryF = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($queryF->have_posts()) :
        $queryF->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();

        $category_detail = get_the_category($id);
        $category = "";
        foreach ($category_detail as $cd) {
            $category .= $cd->cat_name;
            $category .= " &nbsp;|&nbsp; ";
        }
        $category = substr($category, 0, -9);
        $eDate = get_field('event_date', $id);
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M', $eDate);
        $date = $date->format('F');
        $heading = get_the_title($id);
        $short = get_field('short_description', $id);
        $url = get_permalink($id);
        $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id, 'full'); ?>

        <article class="">
            <div class=" ">
                <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="Post image" class="">
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <a href="<?= $url ?>">
                    <p class=""><?php echo $date; ?></p>
                    <h3 class=""><?php echo $heading; ?></h3>
                    <p class=""><?php echo $short; ?></p>
                </a>
                <p class=""><a href="<?= $url ?>" class="">Read more</a></p>

            </div>

        </article>

    <?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This piece of code retrieves events, latest to oldest. But i need a sorted event list which shows upcoming events first, and after upcoming events show finished old events. 

The upcoming events must be as per current date.